# Sorting file list aix one liner

Tags: bash, unix, datetime, sorting, aix

Ok, this is driving me crazy...I have this one liner to find files with text within them..but I cannot get the date and time sorted correctly. It just will not sort properly with a date and time ascending. Any thoughts?

```
$find . -name "dm_rmc_mover*" -mtime -1  -exec grep -il "Error Message: " '{}' \; | xargs ls -ltr
```

Example of output...

```
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       205166 26 Jul 09:35 ./dm_rmc_mover309030.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       209695 26 Jul 09:35 ./dm_rmc_mover309015.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       208945 27 Jul 01:37 ./dm_rmc_mover25405.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       210330 27 Jul 01:37 ./dm_rmc_mover22082.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       210273 27 Jul 01:37 ./dm_rmc_mover22048.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       210330 27 Jul 01:38 ./dm_rmc_mover22059.log
$....
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod         3294 27 Jul 08:38 ./dm_rmc_mover310651.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod         3358 27 Jul 08:38 ./dm_rmc_mover310954.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       177163 27 Jul 08:39 ./dm_rmc_mover276166.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       176643 27 Jul 08:39 ./dm_rmc_mover276577.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       106788 27 Jul 09:12 ./dm_rmc_mover311916.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod         3189 20 Jul 02:22 ./dm_rmc_mover52860.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod         3189 20 Jul 02:22 ./dm_rmc_mover52186.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       194825 20 Jul 11:24 ./dm_rmc_mover377215.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       180234 20 Jul 11:26 ./dm_rmc_mover375105.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       147975 20 Jul 12:24 ./dm_rmc_mover412600.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       208897 20 Jul 12:24 ./dm_rmc_mover411173.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       193887 20 Jul 12:24 ./dm_rmc_mover412596.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod        76626 20 Jul 13:06 ./dm_rmc_mover446896.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       135722 20 Jul 13:06 ./dm_rmc_mover446895.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod       145209 20 Jul 13:08 ./dm_rmc_mover446908.log
$-rw-rw-r--    1 root     d_prod         3272 23 Jul 14:48 ./dm_rmc_mover532883.log
```

Eventually it gets to the the last three files on the 27th!

Comment: Can you post your input/output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are, `xargs` is breaking the file list into several invocations of `ls -ltr`, so you get groups of files that are listed in the proper order, but the output as a whole is not ordered as expected. You can verify if that is the case by adding `-t` or `--verbose` to the `xargs` arguments to print each command before it's executed.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, assuming all the log files are in the same directory, and not in a hierarchy, something like this might work better - untested, but the idea is to generate the list of files in the order you want, then filter by those that match the pattern, then finally to get the `ls -l` output:

```
ls -tr | grep dm_rmc_mover | xargs grep -il "Error Message: " | xargs ls -l
```